# Difference in object boxing / comparing references between C# and VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reference, boxing

I encountered a behavior in VB.NET today regarding boxing and reference comparison that I did not expect. To illustrate I wrote a simple program which tries to atomically update a variable of any type.

Here is a program in C# (https://dotnetfiddle.net/VsMBrg):

```
using System;

public static class Program
{

    private static object o3;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        Test<DateTimeOffset?> value = new Test<DateTimeOffset?>();
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value == null);
        DateTimeOffset dt1 = new DateTimeOffset(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, TimeSpan.Zero);
        DateTimeOffset dt2 = new DateTimeOffset(2017, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, TimeSpan.Zero);

        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(null, dt1));
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value == dt1);

        // this should fail
        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(null, dt2));
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value == dt1);

        // this should succeed
        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(dt1, dt2));
    }
}

public class Test<T>
{


    public T Value {
        get { return (T)System.Threading.Volatile.Read(ref _value); }
    }


    private object _value;

    public bool TrySetValue(T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        object curValObj = System.Threading.Volatile.Read(ref _value);
        if (!object.Equals((T)curValObj, oldValue))
            return false;
        object newValObj = (object)newValue;
        return object.ReferenceEquals(System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, newValObj, curValObj), curValObj);
    }

}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Hello World
True
True
True
False
True
True
```

This is as expected and everything seems to work fine.
Here is the same program in VB.NET (https://dotnetfiddle.net/lasxT2):

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1

    private o3 as object

    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World")

        Dim value As New Test(Of DateTimeOffset?)
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value is nothing)
        Dim dt1 As New DateTimeOffset(2017, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, TimeSpan.Zero)
        Dim dt2 As New DateTimeOffset(2017, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, TimeSpan.Zero)

        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(Nothing, dt1))
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value = dt1)

        ' This should fail
        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(Nothing, dt2))
        Console.WriteLine(value.Value = dt1)

        ' This should succeed
        Console.WriteLine(value.TrySetValue(dt1, dt2))
    End Sub
End Module

public class Test(Of T)


    Public readonly Property Value As T
        Get
            Return CType(Threading.Volatile.Read(_value), T)
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _value As Object

    Public Function TrySetValue(oldValue As T, newValue As T) As Boolean
        Dim curValObj As Object = Threading.Volatile.Read(_value)
        If Not Object.Equals(CType(curValObj, T), oldValue) Then Return False
        Dim newValObj = CObj(newValue)
        Return Object.ReferenceEquals(Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(_value, newValObj, curValObj), curValObj)
    End Function

end class
```

Here the output is:

```
Hello World
True
True
True
False
True
False
```

Here the last statement is false which means that the set did not work.
Am I doing something wrong here or is the problem in the VB.NET?

(Note: Ignore the Volatile reads/writes, this example has no threads so it is not affected by threading)

---

Edit:
If I change the T to integer then everything works OK:
(dotnetfiddle.net/X6uLZs). 
Also if I change T to a custom class it also works OK:
dotnetfiddle.net/LnOOme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the *cause* of this issue is actually VB's `Object` handling, where in some places it's more similar to C#'s `dynamic` than a plain `Object`. Specifically, if I re-write `TrySetValue` as:

```vb
  Public Function TrySetValue(oldValue As T, newValue As T) As Boolean
    Dim curValObj As Object = _value 'Threading.Volatile.Read(_value)
    Console.Write(Object.ReferenceEquals(curValObj,_value))
    If Not Object.Equals(CType(curValObj, T), oldValue) Then Return False
    Dim newValObj = CObj(newValue)
    Return Object.ReferenceEquals(Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(_value, newValObj, curValObj), curValObj)
  End Function
```

We would never expect that `Console.WriteLine` to print `False`. But that's precisely what it does. Decompiling this code back to C# (using Reflector), I obtain this code:

```
public bool TrySetValue(T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    object objectValue = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(this._value);
    Console.Write(object.ReferenceEquals(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(objectValue), RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(this._value)));
    if (!object.Equals(Conversions.ToGenericParameter<T>(objectValue), oldValue))
    {
        return false;
    }
    object obj3 = newValue;
    return object.ReferenceEquals(RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._value, RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(obj3), RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(objectValue))), RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(objectValue));
}
```

Oh dear. What are all of those calls to [`GetObjectValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.getobjectvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) doing here? Well, the *effect* they're having is to cause copies to be made of boxed value types and so `curValObj` never contains an actual reference to the same object as `_value` refers, and so the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` can never work when we're dealing with actual object references.

I can't think of a good way of re-writing this code, presently, to do what you want. And perhaps we can see a *further* reason why the `Object` overload of [`CompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7etff8w(v=vs.110).aspx) warns us:

> Do not use this overload with value types.

Comment: Looking at the IL, the c# instruction is `unbox.any` where the vb instruction is `Conversions.ToGenericParameter<T>`. So that means vb is returning a copy of the struct but c# is referencing the same struct, correct?

Comment: @Crowcoder - the shear number of unexpected copies being made in this small code sample has made me question how any VB code works at all :-(

Comment: From the CLR source code: "Technically we could return boxed DateTimes and Decimals without copying them here, but VB realized that this would be a breaking change for their customers.  So copy them."

Comment: If I change the T to integer then everything works OK:  (https://dotnetfiddle.net/X6uLZs).
Also if I change T to a custom class it also works OK: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LnOOme

Comment: @HansPassant Where is this comment?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L56

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Regarding your comment "Do not use this overload with value types." - I think this is to avoid calling the method with value types which will perform implicit boxing. Anyway I do not think it should apply to this scenario and also the C# version works as expected so this is really a VB.NET issue.

Comment: @DaliborČarapić - I wouldn't describe it as a VB.Net issue without thinking about it a lot more carefully. I'm not *sure* that the C# behaviour is necessarily better. The biggest problem here is that boxing tries to (and does!) cover a lot of sins but at the end of the day value types should have certain semantics (all equal values should compare equal) and *reference* equality doesn't mix well with it. And as I mentioned, I thought this could be an *additional* reason why the warning (re:`CompareExchange`) should be heeded.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I disagree. This has nothing to do with CompareExchange. Lets say you have a method which takes an Object as a parameter. Inside the method you create a new variable of type Object and point it to the Object you received as parameter. You then do ReferenceEqual with your new object reference and the reference you received as parameter, and your references are not equal! Knowing what I know about reference types in .NET I can only cry foul here.